# Question about confilct in result of skipgram function in Keras

Tags: python, keras, word2vec

I have a question about skipgram function in keras.preprocessing.sequence.

In specification, [link](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/), skipgrams function generates negative samples with dictionary.

To understand skipgrams, I print the result of skipgrams function.

I noticed there is a conflicted results, a pair in both side of positive samples and negative samples.

These data does not effect on model?

or

Big dictionary can make ignore these conflicts?

my code is as follows:

```
samplingTable = keras.preprocessing.sequence.make_sampling_table(26)

print (samplingTable)
targetList = [random.randint(0,25) for i in range(200)]

couple, labels = keras.preprocessing.sequence.skipgrams(targetList, 26, sampling_table=samplingTable,shuffle=False )

result= []
for i in range(len(labels)):
    result.append("{}\t{}\t{}".format(couple[i][0],couple[i][1],labels[i]))

for i in sorted(result):
    print (i)
```

and follows are result of code. (8,24), (8,25) are conflicted. (positive 
 1 and negative 0)

```
target  context isExist
8   1   1
8   10  0
8   10  0
8   11  1
8   12  0
8   14  0
8   2   1
8   24  0
8   24  1
8   25  0
8   25  1
```